# Job and Employee Performance Tracking with Product Safety

Tags: database, query, sql, performance

We are looking to connect a WordPress site to our database where an employee can scan an order barcode with an RFID scanner that was generated from our database and have the WordPress site query the order, pulling into a form or table the product names on the order as well as the safety information of those products from specific tables/columns in SQL, then when the employee is done with the order they select done in WordPress so it records a start time based on when they scanned the order barcode and then a finished time that records when they mark as completed as well as a place to scan an employee barcode so it logs the employee name.

Looking for an easy way to do this without extensive programming knowledge.

Comment: Can you break your question up into multiple sentences and paragraphs? it's mostly a single very long sentence which makes it difficult to parse

Comment: The requirement is clear, but if there aren't plugins which do this for you out of the box you'd need to pay someone to build it for you. Sadly there's no magic to take your single-sentence spec and build it easily without programming. It doesn't seem like something that can/should be integrated with Wordpress unless you particularly had a reason to, like your data or users are already in WP for some reason. You might get more mileage from frameworks like rails, django, symfony, etc., which are for building apps like that quickly.